# std::forward and rvalue references in a class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, move, perfect-forwarding

I've been reading about [`std::forward`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves) and I think I understand it well, but I don't think I understand it well enough to use it proficiently enough.

I have a template class that implements a container and has a method called `insert`. I wanted this method to accept constant references and *rvalue* references so that if the inserted element is a rvalue reference, it is moved into the container, not copied. For this, I first overloaded the `insert` method like this:

```
template <typename U>
void do_some_work(U&& x) noexcept
{
    m_data = std::forward<U>(x);
}
void insert(const T& x) 
{
    do_some_work(x);
}
void insert(T&& x) {
    do_some_work(std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

The problem is, these two functions now have to call an "inner" function that implements the assertion. If the functions are small, I guess this is not a problem, but if they are large, it is best to use templates, like this

```
template <typename U>
void insert(U&& x) 
{
    do_some_work(std::forward<U>(x);
}
```

**QUESTION 1**: Is this correct?

---

Now, I want to do the same but with `std::vector`.

```
void insert_vector(const std::vector<T>& v) noexcept {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        do_some_work(v[i]);
    }
}
void insert_vector(std::vector<T>&& v) noexcept 
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) 
    {
        do_some_work(std::forward<T>(v[i]));
    }
}
```

**QUESTION 2**: How do I collapse the `insert_vector` functions into a single one so that the call to `do_some_work` is done with

- rvalue references when the vector is a rvalue reference (specified with `std::move`, for example),
- constant reference when the vector is not given as an rvalue reference, like in `(4)` of the MWE below. The following does not work for me

```
template <typename U>
void insert_vector(U&& v) noexcept 
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) 
    {
        do_some_work(std::forward<T>(v[i]));
    }
}
```

---

Here is a minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class my_class 
{
private:
    T m_data;

private:
    template <typename U>
    void do_some_more_work(U&& x) noexcept {
        m_data = std::forward<U>(x);
    }
    template <typename U>
    void do_some_work(U&& x) noexcept {
        do_some_more_work(std::forward<U>(x));
    }

public:
    void insert(const T& x) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        do_some_work(x);
    }
    void insert(T&& x) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        do_some_work(std::forward<T>(x));
    }
    void insert_vector(const std::vector<T>& v) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            do_some_work(v[i]);
        }
    }
    void insert_vector(std::vector<T>&& v) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            do_some_work(std::forward<T>(v[i]));
        }
    }
};

struct my_struct {
    my_struct() noexcept = default;
    my_struct(int v) noexcept : m_v(v) { }
    my_struct(const my_struct& s) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        m_v = s.m_v;
    }
    my_struct(my_struct&& s) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        m_v = std::move(s.m_v); // not need, but whatever
        s.m_v = -1;
    }
    my_struct& operator= (const my_struct& s) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        m_v = s.m_v;
        return *this;
    }
    my_struct& operator= (my_struct&& s) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        m_v = std::move(s.m_v); // not need, but whatever
        s.m_v = -1;
        return *this;
    }
    int m_v;
};

int main() {
    my_class<my_struct> mc;

    std::cout << "===========================================\n";
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(1.1)\n";
    my_struct s{3};
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    mc.insert(s);
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    }

    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(1.2)\n";
    const my_struct s{3};
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    mc.insert(s);
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "===========================================\n";
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(2.1)\n";
    mc.insert(my_struct{5});
    }
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(2.2)\n";
    my_struct s{5};
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    mc.insert(std::move(s));
    std::cout << s.m_v << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "===========================================\n";
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(3.1)\n";
    std::vector<my_struct> v(5);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { v[i] = my_struct(i); }

    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    mc.insert_vector(v);
    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    }
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(3.2)\n";
    const std::vector<my_struct> v = []() {
        std::vector<my_struct> v(5);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { v[i] = my_struct(i); }
        return v;
    }();

    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    mc.insert_vector(v);
    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "===========================================\n";
    {
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "(4)\n";
    std::vector<my_struct> v(5);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { v[i] = my_struct(i); }

    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    mc.insert_vector(std::move(v));
    for (const auto& s : v) { std::cout << s.m_v << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to solve this issue. I used the same "technique" as with the regular `insert` methods. The full implementation of `my_class` is this. Unfortunately, I could not make a single `insert` method.

```
template <typename T>
class my_class {
private:
    T m_data;

private:
    template <typename U>
    void do_some_more_work(U&& x) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        m_data = std::forward<U>(x);
    }
    template <typename U>
    void do_some_work(U&& x) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        do_some_more_work(std::forward<U>(x));
    }

public:
    template <typename U>
    void insert(U&& x) noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        do_some_work(std::forward<U>(x));
    }

    template <typename U>
    void insert_vector(U&& v) noexcept {
        using elem_t = typename std::remove_reference_t<U>::value_type;

        // this is used here for testing purposes.
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<elem_t, my_struct>);

        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::vector<elem_t>, U>) {
                do_some_work(std::forward<T>(v[i]));
            }
            else {
                do_some_work(v[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
};
```